# Actionscript 3.0 update timer

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, timer

I am working on the sequencer app and I wonder is there a way of updating the timer value

```
        public var stepTimer:Timer = new Timer(300,16);
```

this is my timer and I'd like to change the 300 value for a different song. 
I know this can be easly done with xml but is there any other way??
Thaks

Comment: It is `delay` property , you can change it like: `stepTimer.delay = 200;` . Read more: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#delay

Answer (score 1):

Use `delay` property of the timer in question.

```
stepTimer.delay=1000;
```